# Is the smaller input size quicker on transfer learning to converge and is that ok on seeking better accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, transfer-learning

Hello I'm trying to use transfer learning with Xception and I have a question.
When I do this:

```
xception=Xception(input_shape = (IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_CHANNELS, include_top=False, weights='imagenet')   

IMAGE_WIDTH=192 IMAGE_HEIGHT=256 IMAGE_CHANNELS=3
```

the time for per epoch was about 830s

When I do this:

```
xception=Xception(input_shape = (150, 150, IMAGE_CHANNELS, include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
```

the time for per epoch was about 340s

and also my original image size is IMAGE_WIDTH and IMAGE_HEIGHT

I want to take the latter because it's faster but I want to know your opinion.
To set the input_shape to original size would lead better result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it should lead better results. However, this is highly dependent to your dataset and experimental. It is not possible to say how it will differ in terms of performance, it will be slower for sure.

There is a trade-off.

- Better result --> Slower Model
- Little less good result --> Faster Model

Comment: Thank you for answering Mr Frightera. Okay I understand the model that bring better result tend to be slower. So in most case, input_size == original size lead to a better result? and in my case the time is faster at latter because the input_size is smaller than original?

Comment: In real world scenarios it will not be practical, assume all images are 1024x1024 and CNN model trained on that size. In order to test anything, every image should be 1024x1024, if not we we need to add padding to match the dimensions. In most cases it should lead better results. And that's why it is faster in your case also.

Comment: Okay I understand why the latter was quicker. and in real world, the image size is always need to be 1024 × 1024 but on the way to making a image classification model, input image size don't have to be always 1024 × 1024, correct? After making a model, then change the image size to 1024 × 1024? Sorry maybe it's silly question but I'm new to this field

Comment: You misunderstood, that was an example. It is not always supposed to be 1024x1024. These sizes depend on your data and your computing power.